# Changing sprite at runtime causes it to stop resizing - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resize, sprite

I'm changing the sprite on an Image Component at runtime, and this causes it to stop resizing with the Image's RectTransform and just stays a fixed size. The code that changes the sprite is in Start() method:

```
public Sprite mySprite;

 GetComponent<Image>().sprite = mySprite
```

If I comment it out the image resizes fine so I know this is the problem.

Also, this exact code worked fine in Unity 4, but ever since I updated it won't work.

Comment: that isnt a lot to go on, nor is it a [mcve] Are you getting any errors? theres no code or indication on how this is related to the resizing

Comment: do you mean resizing that it should scale up or just scale the sliced borders? does your "MySprite" Sprite has border/slices defined? otherwise it cannot "scale"

Comment: @Vampirasu It's a simple image that has no borders or anything set.

Comment: @BugFinder I'm starting to think it's a Unity bug because there's not really any code involved besides what I wrote. I put a copy of the prefab being instantiated in the scene in edit mode and played it and it resizes fine. Just when it's instantiated at runtime it doesn't work.

Comment: @BugFinder Also, to clarify, I'm resizing the image by hand in the editor while in play mode. I've also tried setting the RectTransform's sizeDelta through a script which yields the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Image component has Preserve Aspect ticked on, and if it does just untick it. Should solve your problem.

Comment: No, it's not that its not stretching with the RectTransform, it's that is doesn't change size at all. If I increase the size of the RectTransform in both x and y the image stays small in the center of it.